# Conditional addition to back stack

Tags: android

I have the following working code :

```
if (bottomViewState.addToBackStack) {
        fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.bottomNavHostFragment, bottomViewState.fragment, bottomViewState.tag.toString())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
    } else {
        fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.bottomNavHostFragment, bottomViewState.fragment, bottomViewState.tag.toString())
            .commit()
    }
}
```

I use this for a bottom navigation, this way I can navigate back from a detail fragment to it's parent, but I don't add transaction between item of the bottom bar in the back stack. My issue appears when I try to refactor this code to the following :

```
val transaction = fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
transaction.replace(R.id.bottomNavHostFragment, bottomViewState.fragment, bottomViewState.tag.toString())

if(bottomViewState.addToBackStack) {
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
}

transaction.commit()
```

The problem with this code is that my fragment are never displayed, like if the transaction was not committed. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layout, new MyFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```